# How to apply same function to different div's of the same name?

Tags: javascript, html, css, function

When I click on the watch-later icon, the tick will appear correctly.

However, when I apply the same div format to another section, the tick will appear at the first div.

This is my HTML and JavaScript:

```
<div class="hovertext"> <span class="video-txt">01:54</span>
    <span class="watch-later"><input type="image" onclick="showTick()" src="images/watchlater.jpg" /></span>
    <span id="tick" style="display:none;"><input type="image" onclick="conceal()" onMouseOut="hideTick()" src="images/tick.jpg" /></span>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function conceal() {
        if (document.getElementById('tick').style.display == 'block') {
            document.getElementById('tick').style.display = 'none';
        }
    }

    function showTick() {
        if (document.getElementById('tick').style.display == 'none') {
            document.getElementById('tick').style.display = 'block';
        }
    }

    function hideTick() {
        if (document.getElementById('tick').style.display == 'block') {
            document.getElementById('tick').style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
    </script>
</div>
```

It's appearing like this

[image]

I want it to appear like this. How do I change the JavaScript or the div in-line so that it won't affect any other div but yet run the same function?

[image]

Please, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You can have only one element on the page with a given ID. You should pass `this` to the functions, and traverse the DOM to the element you desire. A basic JS/DOM programming tutorial would help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am trying to understand through the formatting, but it seems that it simply has to do with targeting an ID versus a class. HTML only allows for one instance of an ID per page in order to be valid. As this is the case, whenever you target by ID it will likely effect the first instance found. It would be better to have various ID's based on the parent video.

Something like this:

```
<div id="video1" class="hovertext">
    <span class="video-txt">01:54</span>
    <span class="watch-later">
        <input type="image" onclick="showTick()" src="images/watchlater.jpg" />
    </span>
    <span class="tick" style="display:none;">
        <input type="image" onclick="conceal()" onMouseOut="hideTick()" src="images/tick.jpg" />
    </span>
</div>
```

Your javascript should not be included within each parent div either. You should then target the "tick" class of the ID that you are interacting with.

Comment: Hi thank you so much for your help! I tried to target the "tick" class of the ID but doesn't seem to be triggering it. I think there's something wrong with my script.                           Could you help me take a look?                                <script type="text/javascript">
    
   var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("tick");
   
    function conceal() {      

   if (divs.style.display == 'block'){
       divs.style.display= 'none';
   }
 
  }

  function showTick(){

   if (divs.style.display == 'none'){
       divs.style.display= 'block';
   }
  }



    </script>

Comment: @user3534158 - I have created a more in-depth example in a fiddle, here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t3pAs/). It includes styles and jQuery. The jQuery was used for convenience since there could be a number of CSS class items to manipulate. If you need plain JavaScript, I can accommodate next chance I have,

Comment: Any luck @user3534158

Comment: Awesome @user3534158, good to hear! If this answer did indeed work for you can you please accept it as the answer? Thanks, and happy coding!