# Instead of get element by Id. How to get element by class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, styles, inline

It doesn't seem to be working, any idea where i went wrong?
if i use getElementByID..it works.. but not for this. Please help.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function conceal() {
        if (document.getElementsByClassName('tick').style.display == 'block') {
            document.getElementsByClassName('tick').style.display = 'none';
        }
    }

    </script>
```

Comment: Some [search](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName) should be done before asking...

Comment: getElementsByClassName gives an array of all matching classes, even if there is only one.

Comment: It's "Elements" plural for a reason. You get back a **list** of elements.

Comment: Refer this.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17896746/document-getelementsbyclassname-innerhtml-always-returns-undefined

Comment: Class may not be unique like id, so do not use this.

Comment: if u still wana use it try: document.getElementsByClassName('tick')[0].style.display

Answer (score 0):

Use a jQuery class-selector.

```
<p class="myclass">Hello world!</p>
```

Then

```
$(".myclass").doWhatever();
```

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
         function conceal() {     
       
          if($(".tick").style.display=='block'){
        ($(".tick").style.display='none')
       }
        
        }  
      function showTick(){
       if($(".tick").style.display=='none'){
        ($(".tick").style.display='block')
       }
        
    }
 </script>
    
 Is how i write correct? I want to check if i click on the div class="tick" has display block, it will display none.. and vice versa

Comment: @user3534158 You really should do [some search](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/)...

Comment: @teemu I've already did some search. I just dont know why it's not appearing at the correct position. This is my whole question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23073497/how-to-apply-same-function-to-different-divs-of-the-same-name?

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
$('.tick').click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
});
```